# Django sending user password in plain text when using ADMINS

Tags: django, django-registration

I'm utilizing the [ADMINS setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#admins) so Django can send more detailed error logs when my Heroku setup crashes. However, when the error occurs upon/after a user submits a registration form, Django is sending me (alongside the error) their username and password in plain text.

I'm using django-registration and haven't played around with the form at all.

Is this by design? seems incredibly irresponsible to me.

Answer (score 5):

Nah, Django has this thought out :)

You might want to take a look at the [Filtering sensitive information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/error-reporting/#filtering-error-reports) section of the manual.

`django-registration` probably doesn't decorate its registration view/s with [`sensitive_post_parameters()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/error-reporting/#django.views.decorators.debug.sensitive_post_parameters) out of the box, if you're seeing passwords etc.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for the answer. The only problem is I don't really have access to the registration view, which is by design. Guess I'll open a ticket at django-registration.

Comment: Depending on how you include the views, you can decorate the view in your URLconf: `url('^/register/', sensitive_post_parameters(['a', 'b'])(RegistrationView.as_view()), ...)`

Comment: I only now got around to try and implement this and this kind of line: `url(r'^accounts/register$', sensitive_post_parameters(['password1', 'password2'])(RegistrationViewWithContext.as_view(form_class=RegistrationFormUniqueEmail)), name='registration_register'),` simply returns a syntax error.